# create table with records in sql server with powershell: what's best?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, system.data

I need to create and populate a table on sql server db starting from a powershell array of objects coming from `select-object`. I need to create the table with the correct datatypes and fields.

One way that I well know is `export-csv` and then `invoke-sqlcmd` with `BULK INSERT`, but I prefer to skip csv export.

How `invoke-sqlcmd` is normally used to create/populate a table starting from array of hash tables?
Do you know other ways doing the same job without using `invoke-sqlcmd`? Do I need to use `System.Data`? How to?

Thanks

EDIT 1: Another possible way is `New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` by which I could `ExecuteNonQuery()` for each array element.

EDIT 2: Another option, always based on `System.Data`, is update a `SqlDataAdapter` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an blog post for the Scripting Guy that covers just such a scenario

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/01/use-powershell-to-collect-server-data-and-write-to-sql.aspx

Using the code demonstrated in the blog post you can take any PowerShell command create a System.DataTable, then create a SQL Server Table and finally insert the DataTable into the newly created table. Here's an example

```
$dt = get-psdrive | out-datatable
Add-SqlTable -ServerInstance "Z003\R2" -Database dbutility -TableName psdrive -DataTable $dt
Write-DataTable -ServerInstance "Z003\R2" -Database "dbutility" -psdrive"diskspace" -Data $dt
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks very close to my requirements. I'll let you know.

Comment: Do I have to convert my array of hash tables into a datatable before? Is there some easy way to accomplish that, for example just using a `cast`?

Comment: Ok Chad! I've found on the internet the following post at [sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/powershell/65196/), not surprisingly written by you :), where you introduce the `out-datatable` function. Do you think it's a good choice? Does it keep data types? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I consider the Scripting Guy article to be an updated version of teh SQLServerCentral article. PowerShell does a decent job of inferring datatypes, so I haven't messed with expliciting define the type. You would need to use getenumerator with hashtable. Here's an example of using out-datatable with hashtable: $a = @{name='john';dob='1/1/1980';age=31}; $a.GetEnumerator() | out-datatable

Comment: new link for that blog:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-collect-server-data-and-write-to-sql/